# how to update ngFor in html section of angular because of added new member?

Tags: angular

I have an array and used ngFor of it to create some html elements.
My question is about adding new member to my array and update html section just after adding new member.

html section:

```
<div *ngFor="let member of members">
  <span>{{member}}</span>
</div>
```

and ts section:

```
let members: string[] = ['a','b','c','d'];
```

and after rendering html section, somewhere in the application I add `e` element to array but my html section wouldn't change. I want to `e` element to be added immediately.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: What does happen when you push 'e'? If you update the array the view should be updated automatically...

Comment: The binding set up in `*ngFor` provides this behaviour out of the box.

Comment: Are you sure you're adding `e` to the same array? Don't forget that arrays are a reference type.

Comment: @ComicSans I did't know that. :)  thanks.

Comment: So it does work? I'll add an answer below to close this question.

Comment: @WillAlexander I didn't try it before. sorry for my Inappropriate question.

Comment: No worries :-) we all mess up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind an array to a view element like you did in your question. If you change the contents of the array, the view is updated automatically.

You can find the documentation [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)

Answer (score 1):

> When the contents of the iterator changes, `NgForOf` makes the
>   corresponding changes to the DOM:
>
> When an item is added, a new instance of the template is added to the
>   DOM. When an item is removed, its template instance is removed from
>   the DOM. When items are reordered, their respective templates are
>   reordered in the DOM.

any change to the array in you case like add or remove the dom will update automatically base of angular change detection

[*ngFor](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngfor-add-remove-example)